# Proving absolute value inequality with 4 variables

Tags: calculus, inequality

how do i prove the following?

$$\begin{aligned}
|a - b|&<\dfrac{\varepsilon}{2}\\
|b - c|&<\dfrac{\varepsilon}{2}
\end{aligned}$$

Prove that $|a-c|<ε$.  Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Hint**.  By the triangle inequality,
$$|a-c|=|(a-b)+(b-c)|\le|a-b|+|b-c|\ .$$

Comment: got it!thanks!!!